# to divulge how Spirit has

Tags: prepositions, parts-of-speech

1. I share this paper with the objective to divulge how Spirit has guided me.
2. I share this paper with the objective of divulging how Spirit has guided me

Which one is correct ?  or is there a better way to say this

Comment: Are you referring to a particular spirit? (Being Catholic, *the holy spirit* immediately comes to mind.) In which case the article *'the'* would be required.

Comment: yes I was talking about the Universal Spirit :) , thank you

Comment: What kind of spirit, or do you mean *spirituality*?

Comment: my dilemma is on : to divulge or of divulging ?

Comment: Spirit as God or Creator

Comment: Regardless of what "Spirit" refers to, it's [*with the objective **of**...*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=with+the+objective+to%2Cwith+the+objective+of&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwith%20the%20objective%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwith%20the%20objective%20of%3B%2Cc0) But this just looks like proofreading to me.

Comment: Both are fine, albeit awkward sentences that could be rewritten to be both shorter and clearer.

Comment: @FumbleFingers It's just the usual question of "which preposition do I use". Understandable enough.

Comment: I am sorry,,,, obviously English is not my first language... I thank you for your input and comments x

Comment: @SkyRex1: It's the same with similar words such as [***aim***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=with+the+aim+to%2Cwith+the+aim+of&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwith%20the%20aim%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwith%20the%20aim%20of%3B%2Cc0) and [***purpose***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=with+the+purpose+to%2Cwith+the+purpose+of&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwith%20the%20purpose%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwith%20the%20purpose%20of%3B%2Cc0), for example.

Answer (score 2):

As FumbleFingers says, the preposition *of* is normally used with "with the objective" (or *aim*, *purpose*, etc):

> I share this paper with the objective of divulging how the Spirit has guided me.

Note that you the a definite article when talking about a particular person or object (the Universal Spirit).

If you want to use *to divulge* (as in your first example), then you need a different construction:

> I share this paper in order to divulge how the Spirit has guided me.

Comment: As a side note, "I share this paper on how Spirit has guided me" would in most cases be more than enough.  "With the objective of divulging etc." is unnecessarily *wordy*.